# Counting sub groups of table based on filtered subtotals in Dax

Tags: dax

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong in my DAX code for Power BI visuals here?

Requirement: I've got an orders table with lines and header info together. I need to count distinct orders where the order total is > 100. I need it to work sliced out in visuals and standalone as a total. This should be so easy. I've tried this:

```
COUNTX (
    FILTER (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            VALUES ( 'Order'[Order Header Id] ),
            "Orders", 1,
            "Order Values", SUM ( 'Order'[Order Line Value] )
        ),
        [Order Values] > 100
    ),
    [Orders] 
)
```

and this

```
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            VALUES ( 'Order'[Order Header Id] ),
            "Order Values", SUM ( 'Order'[Order Line Value] )
        ),
        [Order Values] > 100
    )
)
```

...and about 100 other variants.
It works when filtered by [Order Header Id] in a visual, but the grand total always equals the total number of orders in the table, regardless of what I do!

I've searched through Russo examples and tried all the usual corners of the internet and can not find the solution. This cannot be this hard.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: It turns out a simple switch from ADDCOLUMNS to SUMMARIZE was the winner!

```
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        SUMMARIZE (
            VALUES ( 'Order'[Order Header Id] ),
            "Order Values", SUM ( 'Order'[Order Line Value] )
        ),
        [Order Values] > 100
    )
)
```

Hopefully this will help someone else some day :)